# Adding elements from text to dictionary

Tags: python

I have a file that have name, password and friends like below

```
john;9999;dave

sam;8888;

dave;7777;alex,john

alex;6666;john,sam,dave
```

I want to add elements to dictionary like this

```
dict1={names:"password"} ,
dict2={names:"friends"}
```

expected Output :

```
{'john':9999,'sam':8888,'dave':7777,'alex':6666}
{'john':dave,'sam':,'dave':alex,john,'alex':john,sam,dave}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1={}
dict2={}

with open('a.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        splitted_data=line.split(';')

        dict1[splitted_data[0]]=splitted_data[1]
        dict2[splitted_data[0]] = splitted_data[2:]


print(dict1) # {'dave': '5678', 'john': '4567', 'sam': '6789', 'alex': '1234'}
print(dict2) # {'dave': ['alex,john\n'], 'john': ['dave\n'], 'sam': ['\n'], 'alex': ['john,sam,dave']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use map on the filestream to get this done.

```py
# Helper function
def myfunc(x):
    x_parts = x.split(';')
    return (x_parts[0], x_parts[1]), (x_parts[0], x_parts[2].strip())

with open(fn) as f:
    dict1, dict2 = tuple(map(dict, list(zip(*list(map(myfunc, f))))))
print(dict1)
print(dict2)
```

Comment: Are all of the lines in your file are of this form - `..str..;..str..;..str..`?

Comment: Yes, like this --- str; str; str

Comment: @Əсҝәран92 Sorry, the file generator would have become empty in the second line. I have modified my answer to correct this.